# Quantified Proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I've been trying to translate the following sentences into quantified propositions by making sure I state all propositional functions that I use and any assumptions that I make.

There is exactly one person who hates everyone.

Let $H(x, y)$ be '$x$ hates $y$,'
where the domain of $x$ is all people in the world.

Then, $\exists x \forall y\ (\ H(x,y)\ \land \forall z\ (z \neq x) \rightarrow \neg H(z,y)\ ) $.

Can you see if I'm on the right track here?

Comment: Just to clarify, does that one person hate themself as well? (I would assume so)

Comment: Yes. Does that make any difference to my answer?

Comment: @yellowhellow Are you familiar with $\exists!$, the unique existential quantifier? If not, you may want to check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119836/logic-how-to-write-exists-x-without-the-exists-symbol/1119847#1119847) post.

Comment: I know the use of that quantifier. But, I do not want to use it for this example.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement, as it reads now, means:

> There exists one such person $x$ that for every other person $y$, $x$ hates $y$ and nobody else hates $y$.

That is not what you want to state. For example, if

- $A$ hates $A$, $B$ and $C$ and
- $B$ hates $C$,

then the original statement (there exists a person who hates everybody) is *true*, but your statement is *false* (because it is not true that nobody else hates $C$)

Comment: $\exists x\ (\ \forall y\ H(x,y)\ \land \forall z \exists y\ (z \neq x) \rightarrow \neg H(z,y)\ ) $               Is this correct?

Comment: @yellowhellow Yes. That looks better.

Comment: Is there a way to get better at these things? I mean, they always confound me, even after I check and recheck my answers.

Comment: @yellowhellow The standard way of saying "there exists exactly one $x$ for which $p(x)$ is true" is to write $\exists x: (p(x) \wedge \forall x': p(x') \implies x=x')$

Comment: I was wondering if it shouldn't rather be $\exists x \forall y\ (\ H(x,y)\ \land \forall z\ (z \neq x) \rightarrow \exists y\ \neg H(z,y)\ ) $ ?

Comment: The OP's proposed solution doesn't exclude the possibility that $x=y$ as you claim.

Comment: or say $\exists x \forall y\ (\ H(x,y)\ \land \forall z\ (\forall y\ H(z,y))\ \rightarrow (z=x)\ ) $

Answer (score 0):

$\exists!x\forall yH(x,y)$, where $\exists!$ is the *unique* existential quantifier.

Comment: I know the use of that quantifier. But, I do not want to use it for this example.

Comment: @yellowhellow Why not? You seem to be unnecessarily complicating things.

Comment: I want to make sure I fully understand how to do it the hard way, before I do it the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

To say "there exists a unique $x$ for which the predicate $P$ holds" : we usually say "there exists some $x$ for which the predicate holds and if the predicate holds for anything it is that $x$".

$$ \exists x \Big(P(x)\wedge \forall z\big(P(z)\to x=z\big)\Big) $$

We *can* use the contrapositive.

$$ \exists x \Big(P(x)\wedge \forall z\big(x\neq z \to \neg P(z)\big)\Big) $$

Or more breifly: $$ \exists x\;\forall z \Big(x=z \leftrightarrow P(z) \Big)$$

And you want to do this for the predicate "$x$ hates every one". $$P(x) \;\equiv \;\forall y\; H(x,y)\\ \neg P(x) \;\equiv\; \exists y\;\neg H(x,y)$$

So: ...